# Adding <slot> in repeating content region

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a menu component which, simplistically, takes in an prop with an array of options and renders an item in the menu for each one. I wanted to be able to customise the markup that was inside each of the menu items depending on the use-case so I used the  placeholder inside the menu item element.

You can see an example of this in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugf8sn83/).

```
const Menu = {
    template: `
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in options" :class="item.colour">
            <slot></slot>
            <span class="label">{{item.name}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
    `,
    data: () => {
        return {
            options: [
                { name: 'one', colour: 'red' },
                { name: 'two', colour: 'green' },
                { name: 'three', colour: 'blue' },
                { name: 'four', colour: 'yellow' }
            ]
       };
    }
};


const app = new Vue({
    components: {
        custommenu: Menu,
      },
    template: `<custommenu><span class="colour"></span></custommenu>`
});

app.$mount('#app');
```

This worked fine on v1 of Vue.JS but after upgrading to v2 I'm seeing the error "Duplicate presence of slot "default" found in the same render tree - this will likely cause render errors. "

Is this something that is possible in v2 or is there an alternative way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you will need a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots) for this, so you will need to wrap your `slot` content in a template with a `scope` attribute:

```
<custommenu>
  <template scope="colour">
    <span class="colour"></span>
  </template>
</custommenu>
```

Then you will need to add that to the slot in your component template:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in options" :class="item.colour">
    <slot colour></slot>
    <span class="label">{{item.name}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kLge4wun/

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - it works well. I should have spotted scoped slots in the docs!