# Slot duplicate name Vuejs(Duplicate presence of slot )

Tags: javascript, components, vuejs2, slot

i have component with slot

```
 <carousel 
      <div slot="bloger-avatar">avatar</div>                               
  </carousel>
```

and iterate in child

```
<div class="swiper-slide" v-for="(slide,index) in slideArray" :key="index">
            <slot name="bloger-avatar"></slot>
            <img :src="slide" alt="index"/>
            <!-- slide-item -->
          </div>
```

Please help me: how can i avoid duplicating of slot name, but iterate in child(because as i understand slot-scope assume iteration in parent  )

Comment: May be this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41851062/1292050